# Execution Failed for task ':mergedDebugResources' in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to build my android app, I get the following error:

> Error: Gradle: Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

I have tried all the different methods suggested in the other threads of similar nature, but none work. I would highly appreciate any inputs.

Here is the gradle console output:

https://gist.github.com/nmakes/bcddee7f136e821cc5b451013db2b315

I have the following build.gradle file:

```
buildscript{
    repositories{
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.BP_Monitor"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

And the gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
#Thu May 25 15:57:26 GMT+05:30 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

settings.gradle file contains:

```
include ':app'
```

PS: I am a little new to Android. Pardon me for a repetitve question. Let me know if any other file is required.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue and then go to toolbar -> Help Menu -> Show log in Finder and then post the log here?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nmakes/50bd98d3776e6c4068debb5668a3e5f1

   Here's the log file

Comment: What is the command that you are running from the console?  There are several errors in the log file, but nothing to do with file crunching.  Also does your project have other Gradle files, the logs indicated a problem finding a plug-in that isn't included in the Gradle file posted as part of the question.